# CSS apply property to just the first created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm appending buttons to a div as detailed here - [Append button to div using javascript](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjqgdQ)

Every button gets added through a `addBtns();` function call. Hence, the CSS applied gets applied to every button that gets appended to the div.

The problem I have is I want the buttons to be aligned at the bottom right hand corner of the div. I tried setting `top-margin` & `left-margin` properties. With the `left-margin`, the problem I have is the margin gets applied to every button & hence the spacing between the buttons changes.

I'd like the `left-margin` to be applied only for the first button that gets created in that div which in this case is button labelled `'A'`

Could I please request help to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: Please don't just *link* to your code, *include* your code *in the question*, otherwise, if the external link dies, gets moved, reorganised or is simply unavailable your question is immediately made nonsensical and unhelpful to others. Please see the "[ask]" and "[mcve]" guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by pure CSS:

```
 input:first-child {
     margin-left: 30%;
 }
```

It will work for dynamically created elements as well. I had to add `width:50%;` to `appendToMe` because it did not have any width originally. Additionally, I added `margin-left:30%` instead of `300%` because it obviously goes outside of the boundaries.

Check it out on [**CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/QyZXxO)

Comment: Hello - Thank you for this. I've updated the codepen by adding the below -     `.appendToMe button:first-child {
      margin-left: 100%;
    }` where `appendToMe` is the name of the class added to the `div`. However, I still don't see it take effect. Am I using the right syntax? This is the first time I'm using this.

Comment: @usert4jju7 They are <input> tags not <button>.

Comment: Thank you Pangloss :) That's right. The wording I used was button while I was trying input. Good stuff. I fixed it with this on -     `.appendToMe  input:first-child{
      margin-left: 70%;
    }`

Comment: I just updated my answer with an example. check it out

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the CSS `:first-child` pseudo-class. Details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child